# Java Array Iterator

Tags: java, arrays

This is the example that I found online(I modified it) with a method that returns array. The array being passed is iterated to be a new array in a reversed order.

```
public class MultDim {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double[] myList = {1.9, 2.9, 3.4, 3.5};
        double[] returned = returnArr(myList);
        for (double elem : returned) {
            System.out.println(elem);
        }
    }

    public static double[] returnArr(double[] list) {
        double[] result = new double[list.length];
        for (int i = 0, j = list.length - 1; i < list.length; i++, j--) {
            result[j] = list[i];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

What I want is to pass the elements of the array being passed to the method to be in the same order in the array that is returned. Here is how I  tried to solve it. But is returns an error which is(The primitive type int of list.length does not have a field i)

```
public class MultDim {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] myList = {1.9, 2.9, 3.4, 3.5};
        double[] returned = returnArr(myList);
        for (double elem : returned) {
            System.out.println(elem);
        }
    }


    public static double[] returnArr(double[] list) {
        double[] result = new double[list.length];
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < list.length, i < list.length; i++, j++) {
            result[j] = list[i];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I am just wondering what I concept missed from this.

Comment: I suspect the problem is this part: `j < list.length, i < list.length` - I imagine that's expected to only ever be a single boolean condition. That said, since both `i` and `j` are going to be the same value, and `list` and `result` will both have the same length, you can get rid of `j` entirely: `for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {result[i] = list[i];}`.

Comment: And if he wants anyway to check i and j: `j < list.length && i < list.length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stop condition in the `for` loop can't write as this

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; j < list.length, i < list.length; i++, j++)
```

in this situation a simple

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < list.length; i++, j++)
```

is good enough

or just:

```
for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){
     result[i] = list[i];
}
```

Comment: new is a reserved keyword

Comment: sorry for that, I just edit it while you are posting

Comment: @armnotstrong so I am not supposed to put two conditions that way. thank you for the solution.

Comment: yes, the stop condition required to be a boolean expression

Answer (score 1):

The compiler error is due to the condition in the `for` loop. `j < list.length, i < list.length` is an invalid condition. If you meant both `j < list.length` and `i < list.length`, then use the logical AND operator (`&&`):

```
j < list.length && i < list.length
```

Having said this, you don't need to use both `i` and `j` in the loop since the returned array has the same size as the array passed as an argument. So you could just do with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    result[i] = list[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look on how a `for` needs to be constructed

```
for (init; stop_condition; actions)
```

`init` can be a list of java initialisation, separated with comma (`,`)

`stop_condition` needs to be a single java expression that evaluates to a boolean, in your case it should be :

```
j < list.length && i < list.length
```

action can be a list of java expressions, separated with comma (`,`)

way more simple you could write (as i and j are always the same):

```
for(int i = 0;i < list.length; i++)
{
    result[j] = list[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the code's in first image will reverse array fields 
but this is yours and will worked!

```
public class MultDim {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] myList = {1.9, 2.9, 3.4, 3.5};
    double[] returned = returnArr(myList);
    for (double elem : returned) {
        System.out.println(elem);
    }
}


 public static double[] returnArr(double[] list) {
    double[] result = new double[list.length];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < list.length && i < list.length; i++, j++) {
        result[j] = list[i];
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the *actual* problem - how to copy array data you should probably use the functions provided by the Java libraries.

Example:

```
final double[] copy1 = Arrays.copyOf(myList, myList.length);
```

Other options include [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)).